# How to get toggle style change when mouse over and mouse leave in jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle, element, parent

I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(body').mousemove(function (evt) {

        // i want code 1.
        $(evt.target).mouseover('background-color', 'blue');
        $(evt.target).leave('background-color', 'before color');

        // i want code 2.
        $(evt.target.parent).mouseover('background-color', 'yellow');
        $(evt.target.parent).leave('background-color', 'before color');
    }
}
```

i dont know this pixing code. 
please help me guys!!

thank you.

Comment: 1. You're missing a `'` on the jQuery object's selector. 2. This isn't valid jQuery. You should be using `css()`, or preferably `addClass()`, to amend the styling within the events. 3. It's rather odd to do this on `mousemove` on the `body` element. Once the mouse has moved once the background will change and can never be changed back to it's original; there would be no 'toggle' effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` with add and remove class.

```js
$('.target').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).addClass("target1");
  $(this).parent().addClass("parent1");
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("target1");
  $(this).parent().removeClass("parent1");
});
```

```css
.target1 {
  background-color: blue
}

.parent1 {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
  sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt
  ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem
  <div class="target">
    <h1>Hover me I show you a result.</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $('.box').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).css({
      'background-color': 'blue'
    });
  });

  $('.box').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).css({
      'background-color': 'yellow'
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `hover` event instead :

```js
$(".element").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow'); //When mouse enter
  },
  function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'green'); //When mouse leave
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element">My div</div>
```